# How the count of views is done?

Tags: discussion

How is the views counted?

> 1)From one IP -one view.
>
> 2)From one account - one view?

Edits:

> 1)Is the views incremented by the visits of the author?
>
> 2) Is it the same case with profile views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was discussed on Meta StackOverflow many times. One [user's analysis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-does-stack-overflow-calculate-the-number-of-views-in-a-question/36729#36729) led to the following conclusion: repeated visitors by the same user within the same quarter-hour (such as 11:15-11:30) do not increase the view count. "Same user" means userid for identified users, or IP address for anonymous browsing. Server-side code could have been changed over time (the post was written in 2011), but the client-side part is here now as it was then. The following is taken from the source of this page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
StackExchange.ready(function(){$.get('/posts/7079/ivc/875a');});
</script>
<noscript>
<div><img src="/posts/7079/ivc/875a" class="dno" alt="" width="0" height="0"></div>
</noscript>
```

Indeed looks like a counter, with a fallback for disabled Javascript. The four-character code `875a` at the end of URL above is the same for all posts on the site, and also for all profiles *except for your own profile* which does not have a counter (see below). It is a coarse timestamp that changes every 15 minutes:

```
Jan.4 21:49 UTC: d51a 
Jan.4 22:38 UTC: 175b
Jan.4 22:57 UTC: d6da
Jan.4 23:23 UTC: d29a
Jan 4 23:32 UTC: 125b
Jan.4 23:47 UTC: 2499
```

Edit: Views of your own *profile* do not increase the number of profile views, according to the `status-completed` tag on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12766/can-user-profile-views-not-include-narcissism-please), and the fact that the code quoted above is not found there.

On the client-side the counter on profile page looks just like on a question page, but they could be treated differently by the server for all we know. Only SE developers would know for sure what happens there, but I think they are not too keen to disclose the details about how the system can be gamed by users hunting for the `Famous Question` badge.

Comment: does viewing a question you asked change the view count?